# Renaming file numbers of a file name in Linux

Tags: linux, command, rename, mv

I have 500 files with name as `file_0.yuv , file_1.yuv, file_2.yuv .....file_499.yuv`

I want to rename the file with adding 500 into the file number in each file name

For example:

```
file_0.yuv -> file_500.yuv
file_1.yuv -> file_501.yuv
file_2.yuv -> file_502.yuv
...
file_499.yuv -> file_999.yuv
```

I tried to use :

```
for i in `seq 0 499`; do mv file_$i.yuv file_$i+500.yuv; done
```

But that does not serve the purpose as file name come to : `file_0+500.yuv`

Can any one suggest me the correct command here ?

UPDATE:

I am using bash script.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us which shell you use. (`bash`?)

Answer (score 4):

If your shell is `bash` you can use `$(( ... ))` for arithmetic.

```
for i in `seq 0 499`; do mv file_$i.yuv file_$((i+500)).yuv; done
```

Instead of using backticks `` `foo` `` you should prefer to use `$(foo)`

```
for i in $(seq 0 499); do mv file_$i.yuv file_$((i+500)).yuv; done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably also use sequences, at the possible loss of some portability.

```
for s in {0..499}; do mv file_$i.yuv file_$((i+500)).yuv; done
```